# Сложности с запятыми

Tags: пунктуация

Как я понимаю, запятая существует для того, чтобы интонационно отделять одни слова или части предложений от других. Для этого она была придумана. Но тогда возникает резонный вопрос: зачем и откуда такие сложности с постановкой запятых? Все эти сложные обороты "совсем как", "более чем" и т.д. Если уж интонационный знак, так пусть и будет интонационным, к чему столько сложностей? Причем, как я понимаю, все эти нагромождения пунктуационных правил свойственны именно русскому языку.
Буду благодарен за разъяснение этого вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Вы ошибаетесь.
Запятая, как и любой пунктуационный*) знак служит отнюдь не только целям интонационным.

Вообще принципов русской орфографии по разным оценкам - от трех до пяти. Главный в любом случае - грамматический (синтаксический), направленный на передачу внутренней структуры предложения и его частей. Далеко не всегда она совпадает с интонационным членением.

Интонационный принцип обычно идет третьим, после смыслового.   
http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=5.14

Там есть и описание основной (в русском языке) функции запятой.

*В середине предложения членят текст на равнозначные грамматически и логически отрезки и ставятся между частями сложного предложения, однородными членами простого.*

//---

Я оговорюсь, что в других языках принципы могут быть иные, поэтому ваше соображение насчет того запятая "придумана" для интонационного членения фразы, в чем-то может быть и верно, но только не для русского языка.

Я слышал, что первые знаки препинания, функционально близкие современным русским, впервые появились в армянском. Вот тут [@Серж](/users/1826/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6) есть, возможно он даст справку, если ему это интересно. Может быть, там как раз и реализован принцип интонационной пунктуации.

//===
*) даже орфографический - если рассматривать пунктуацию как часть орфографии в широком смысле, т.е. "правильнописания".

Comment: Да, вы почти правы, behemothus. Только первые знаки препинания восходят к древнегреческому языку, откуда были заимствованы армянским языком приблизительно в 5 веке( в древнеармянском языке  - грабаре). Там использовалось три пунктуационных и десять интонационных знаков. Русская же пунктуация сложилась сравнительно поздно - к началу 19 века и в основных чертах сходна с пунктуацией других европейских языков.Но в армянском языке, действительно, наблюдается некоторая функциональная схожесть с русской пунктуацией.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы текст понимался быстро и правильно, его делят на части с помощью пунктуационных знаков, в том числе запятых. Весь вопрос состоитв том, как наилучшим образом это сделать.

В основе русской пунктуации лежат три основных принципа: семантический (смысловой),  грамматический (структурно-синтаксический) и интонационный. В действительности,  эти три принципа тесно связаны между собой, как связаны ФОРМА и СОДЕРЖАНИЕ любого явления.

1)Семантический (смысловой)  принцип. Письмо должно точно выражать содержание высказывания, при этом  знаки препинания должны способствовать ЯСНОСТИ В ИЗЛОЖЕНИИ МЫСЛЕЙ, в отделении одной части высказывания от другой.

2) Интонационно-грамматический принцип. СОДЕРЖАНИЕ речи выражается ФОРМОЙ речи, которая основывается на двух принципах – грамматическом и интонационном.

Интонация  и грамматика предложений тесно связаны  собой:  простое предложение, сложное предложение, предложения с однородными и обособленными членами – все эти синтаксические конструкции имеют определенную  интонацию.Соответственно, во многих случаях интонационный и грамматический принципы постановки знаков препинания следует рассматривать как единый интонационно-грамматический принцип.

Только грамматический или только интонационный принципы являются частными случаями в общей системе пунктуации.

Таким образом, устная речь делится на речевые отрезки с помощью интонации, а письменная - с помощью знаков препинания, которые в общем случае соответствуют друг другу. Но в обоих случаях решается общая главная задача - понять грамматику предложения и его смысл.

ИСТОРИЯ ПУНКТУАЦИИ

В древнерусской письменности текст не членился на слова и предложения, однако уже тогда встречались такие знаки препинания,   как точка, крест, волнистая черта. Они  делили текст на смысловые отрезки или обозначали остановку в работе писца, однако в дальнейшем эти знаки не получили широкого распространения.

Начиная с XVI века в рукописных изданиях утверждается принцип раздельного написания слов, и между словами и предложениями начинают ставиться знаки препинания.

Большое значение для развития пунктуации имело введение книгопечатания. В середине XV века итальянские типографы изобрели пунктуацию для европейской письменности, которая была принята в основных чертах большинством стран Европы и существует до сих пор.

Современная русская пунктуация является  результатом длительного и сложного взаимодействия той пунктуационной системы, которая была установлена в европейских странах после введения книгопечатания, и тех приёмов употребления знаков, которые складывались в русской письменности с XVIII столетия и до настоящего времени.

ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ

Древнейшим знаком препинания является точка, которая  встречается уже в памятниках древнерусской письменности.Различались точки разного вида: СРОКА — точка в середине строки  и СОБСТВЕННО ТОЧКА, которая ставилась внизу, причем они  могли быть разного размера и цвета.

Наиболее распространённым знаком препинания в русском языке считается запятая (от глагола  пять в значении держать, останавливать), этот знак встречается уже в XV веке. Запятая указывала на незаконченность действия и давала возможность сделать паузу при чтении.

Двоеточие  как разделительный знак начинает употребляться с конца XVI века.Оно упоминается в грамматиках Лаврентия Зизания, Мелетия Смотрицкого (1619) , а также в первой русской грамматике доломоносовского периода В. Е. Адодурова (1731).

Тире – от tirer (фр.) – растягивать, знак препинания, который применяется во многих языках. Его название установилось не сразу. В «Российской грамматике А.А. Барсова (1771 год)  он назвается «молчанка», затем «черта». В русскую письменность тире ввел Н. М. Карамзин. Этот знак часто встречается в его «Бедной Лизе».Слово тире встречается с  начала 1820 годов. А. Х. Востоков в «Сокращенной русской грамматике» (1831 год) назвал его «знаком мыслеотделительным».

В  русском языке XVI-XVIII веков вопросительный знак назывался «точка вопросительная».
Он отмечен  в печатных книгах  XVI века, однако для выражения вопроса  закрепляется значительно позже, лишь в XVIII веке.Первоначально в значении [?] употреблялся знак [;].

Восклицательный знак назывался «точка  удивления».Правила постановки «удивительного знака»  определяются в  «Российской грамматике» М. В. Ломоносова (1755).